# Best way to work on an array of structs within a struct

Tags: rust, memory-management

I have a big complicated struct (in the example, `BigStruct`) with a list of objects of a different struct (in the example, `LittleStruct`). At some point I want to iterate through all the `LittleStruct` objects in the `BigStruct` and perform some code that will modify both each `LittleStruct` object and the overall `BigStruct` object.

That is, it looks something like this:

```
struct LittleStruct {
      // various data
}

impl LittleStruct {
     fn process_one_little_struct(&mut self, container: &mut BigStruct) {
           // do various things
     }
}

struct BigStruct {
     list: Vec<LittleStruct>
}

impl BigStruct {
     fn process_little_structs(&mut self) {
           for i in 0..self.list.len(){
               self.list[i].process_one_little_struct(self);
           }
     }
}
```

This gives the error:

> error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time

I can see why it's mutably borrowed twice (once to get the list, and again in the function call), and I think I understand why it's reasonable not to borrow itself mutably twice -- what if it deletes the exact little struct that is supposed to run `process_one_little_struct`? But I'm wondering what I can do to save the logic here.

Ideally, what I would like to tell the compiler is: `process_one_little_struct` may modify a lot of different parts of `BigStruct`, but it will not modify the variable `list`. Or if it does, then feel free to delete the object when returning from `process_one_little_struct`.

I think I could move all the code from `process_one_little_struct` into the loop in `process_little_structs`. It would be annoying (and possibly slow?) to be constantly looking up the `LittleStruct` that I want (though I could define some sort of reference to it). Plus, I would need to set a bunch of properties to be public, or create a lot of wrapper functions. Is that the only way? I'm new to Rust so I don't know exactly how the memory management is working here.

Comment: If you know `process_one_little_struct` won't modify `BigStruct::list`, you should be able to pass parts of `BigStruct` without needing all of `self`. Ex: `self.list[i].process_one_little_struct(&mut self.other_data)`

Comment: That would work, except in the ideal future for this code, there is an unspecified type which should have access to a series of functions of `BigStruct` that require mutable access to self. But maybe the thing to do is to put all of the mutable components in another struct that can be passed around mutably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy solution to this problem (although [there were some ideas](https://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2021/11/05/view-types/)). Generally, there are three things you can do in this case:

1. Re-architect your code so this will not be needed.
2. Split the container struct, and pass only reference to the data that `process_one_little_struct()` needs. Sometimes this is very artificial, sometimes this is actually a better design.
3. Pass the necessary information to `process_one_little_struct()` so it will be able to re-create `self` and make it an associated method. In this case, pass it the index. You can bind it at the beginning of the function to simplify it:

```rust
pub fn process_one_little_struct(container: &mut Container, i: usize) {
    let this = &container.list[i];
    // ...
}
```

You can use shared ownership (`Rc` and friends), but assuming your ownership isn't *actually* shared and you just need temporary access this is probably not a good idea.

Comment: These are all very helpful. I ended up going with option 2, and split off all modifiable data into a `BigStructPublicAPI` struct, which `BigStruct` contains an instance of that it passes around as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you're making a single threaded application then you can use the Rc smart pointer provided by the Rust standard library. You can read more about it in it's [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) but essentially what it does is, it counts the active references of a variable and drops it as it goes out of bounds. Note that if you want to use multiple references concurrently, you'd need to use something like Arc smart pointer from std::sync. You can read more about it in it's [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html).

Answer (score 0):

For my specific situation, the following restructure worked:

```
struct LittleStruct {
      // various data
}

impl LittleStruct {
     fn process_one_little_struct(&mut self, container: &mut BigStructPublicAPI) {
           // do various things
     }
}

struct BigStructPublicAPI {
      // Any publicly modifiable data 
}

struct BigStruct {
     list: Vec<LittleStruct>,
     public_api: BigStructPublicAPI
}

impl BigStruct {
     fn process_little_structs(&mut self) {
           for i in 0..self.list.len(){
               self.list[i].process_one_little_struct(&mut self.public_api);
           }
     }
}
```

In my case it was generally obvious for all the data in `BigStruct` whether it would need to be modified during subroutines of objects it contained, so that let me split the data between `BigStruct` and `BigStructPublicAPI`.